# Openshift 3.X with Websockets

Tags: websocket, openshift

I'm trying to host a websocket-application op Openshift 3, but I have running into some issues.

Code at the backend:

```
templatePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
staticPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")

settings = {
    "template_path": templatePath,
    "static_path": staticPath,
    "debug" : True
}

application = web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
    (r'/', MainHandler, {"staticFilesPath":staticPath}),
    (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': staticPath}),
],**settings)

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self, messageHandler):
        print 'Initializing MessageHandler'
        self.messageHandler = messageHandler

    def check_origin(self,origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print 'Connection received'

    def on_message(self, message):
        message = simplejson.loads(message)
        print 'received message of type "' + message['type'] + '"'

    outputMessage = {'type': 'Hello', 'data': 'World'}
    self.sendMessage(outputMessage)

def on_close(self):
    print 'Connection closed'

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, staticFilesPath):
        self.staticFilesPath = staticFilesPath

    def get(self):
        print 'New connection'    
        webClientHtml = os.path.join(self.staticFilesPath,'index.html')
        loader = tornado.template.Loader(".")
        self.write(loader.load(webClientHtml).generate())
```

At the frontend:

```
var hostname = window.document.location.hostname;
var host = "ws://" + hostname + ":8000/ws";

var ws = new WebSocket(host);
```

This leads to ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I know the port 8000 had to be specified in Openshift 2. The documentation I could find about websocket-ports op Openshift 3 seems to suggest this is no longer necessary, but I can't figure out what to use. I have tried 80 and not specifying a port, but neither works.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using the Python S2I builder for OpenShift 3 it requires your application code to internally use port 8080, not 8000.  The one port handles both normal HTTP traffic and web socket requests. Externally, your web application is visible on normal port 80 though, so don't have the client using port 8000 or 8080 as nothing listening on that.

Comment: I got it working with:  "ws://" + hostname + "/ws"; Thanks

Comment: This helped me, thanks !
I suggest you add this as an answer to the question (for better visibility)