# Openshift Online 3 with WebSockets. What is the correct "ws"?

Tags: java, websocket, openshift, tomcat8

The problem is that after migrate from Openshift 2 to Openshift 3 I can't get WebSockets communication.
[Here is the same question but it doesn't work for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270244/openshift-3-x-with-websockets)

I've got:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

After refresh the same page:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503

This is my code

```
var wsUri ="ws://" + document.location.host + "/scada1WebSockEndpoint"
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

And it works on my local Apache but does not work on Openshift platform. For me it looks like the websocket doesn't work at all or the `wsUri` incorrect.
Any idea?

Comment: What port number are you trying to connect to from outside of OpenShift? In V2 you had to use a separate port. In V3 it is the normal port 80/443 depending on whether using insecure or secure connection.

Comment: where should I point out the port number?
In V2 I did `var wsUri = "wss://canconnectweb-sergeylotvin.rhcloud.com:8443/scada1WebSockEndpoint";`

In V3 this option doesn't work - `var wsUri ="ws://" + document.location.host + ":80/scada1WebSockEndpoint"` I tried 8080 and 443 and 8443. Nothing helped.

Comment: Don't include ``:8443``. Use the hostname corresponding to the route you created for the application and which exposed it outside of the cluster. Use ``oc get routes`` to find that out, or look in the web console overview page.

Comment: Well, it is like in my start message. I tried `var wsUri ="ws://" + document.location.host + "/scada1WebSockEndpoint"` Ports didn't mention here. `document.location.host` - changed to real app name (route that is exactly the same as exposed). `scada1WebSockEndpoint` - it's just the name of endpoint.

Comment: Have you added any debug to display what ``document.location.host`` is being calculated as to verify it? Do you have a way of running a client inside of the container from the command line, which will talk to ``localhost:8080`` to verify that the application is handling then websocket request okay?

Comment: You also could use port fowarding to expose port 8080 to your local computer and bypass the haproxy to verify that the haproxy isn't causing the issue.

Comment: If I understood correctly your question...So I have `writeToScreen("wsUri is -->"+wsUri);` later in the code. I display it just on the *.jsp and the result `wsUri` match the `hostname`

Comment: Hmm...I've forwarded the port and the error 404 remains. Either if I just go `localhost:localPortForwarded/webSocketName` or if from local Apache try to use `localhost:localPortForwarded/webSocketName` as an WebSoscket server.

Comment: Do normal HTTP request to other parts of your application work via the forwarded port? Or is the application web socket only? What language and stack is the application accepting the requests implemented in?

Comment: HTTP works fine. I use MySQL DB located on cloud and all data recevied by client correctly. Then the exchange between MySQL DB also works. Stack - JAVA, Maven, ApacheTomcat 8, MySQL, JS. Everything works on my local ApacheTomcat 8 and only websockets doesn't work for deployed to Openshift 3 project. I will try to use WildFly instead of Apache on Openshift, maybe it'll help...

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't say that the problem solved, but I forced it work at least. I've just changed the type of server inside the Openshit Online 3. From **Red Hat JBoss Web Server 3.0 Tomcat 8** to **Red Hat JBoss Web Server 3.0 Tomcat 7**.
So it works now for **Red Hat JBoss Web Server 3.0 Tomcat 7** on the cloud and Tomcat 8 on local PC. It means that the problem connects to Tomcat 8. But where could it be? Any idea would be appreciated.