# Connecting to Websocket in OpenShift Online Next Gen Starter

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-3

I'm in the process of trying to get an application which I'd built on the old OpenShift Online 2 free service up and running on the new OpenShift Online 3 Starter, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

The application uses websocket, and in the old system all that was required was for the client to connect to my server on port 8443 (which was automatically routed to my server). That doesn't seem to work in the new setup however - the connection just times out - and I haven't been able to find any documentation about using websocket in the new system.

My first thought was that I needed an additional rout, but 8080 is the only port option available for routing as far as I can see.

The app lives [here](http://production-instanttabletop.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com/), and the connection is made on line 21 of [this script](http://production-instanttabletop.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com/client/js/tabletop.js) with the line:

```
    this.socket = new WebSocket( 'wss://' + this.server + ':' + this.port, 'tabletop-protocol' );
```

Which becomes, in practice:

```
    this.socket = new WebSocket( 'wss://production-instanttabletop.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com:8443/', 'tabletop-protocol' );
```

On the back end, the server setup is unchanged from what I had on OpenShift 2, aside from updating the IP and port lookup from `env` as needed, and adding logging to help diagnose the issues I've been having.

For reference, here's the node.js server code (with the logic trimmed out):

```
var http = require( "http" );
var ws = require( "websocket" ).server;
// Trimmed some others used by the logic...

var ip = process.env.IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0';
var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

/* FILE SERVER */

// Create a static file server for the client page
var pageHost = http.createServer( function( request, response ){

    // Simple file server that seems to be working, if a bit slowly
    // ...

} ).listen( port, ip );

/* WEBSOCKET */

// Create a websocket server for ongoing communications
var wsConnections = [];
wsServer = new ws( { httpServer: pageHost } );

// Start listening for events on the server
wsServer.on( 'request', function( request ){

    // Server logic for the app, but nothing in here ever gets hit
    // ...

} );
```

In another question it was suggested that nearly anything - including this -
 could be related to the to the ongoing general issues with US West 2, but other related problems I was experiencing seem to have cleared, and that issue has been posted for a week with no update, so I figured I'd dig deeper into this on the assumption that it's something *I'm* doing wrong instead of them.

Anyone know more about this and what I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the same 8080 port?

Comment: Clarification on what @WillGordon may be suggesting. The external OpenShift ports for access both via HTTP and WS will be port 80 and HTTPS and WSS will be 443 (if exposed via secure route). That is, the standard ports. There is no separate 8080/8443 with OpenShift 3. To test access and eliminate the OpenShift router as causing an issue, you can use ``oc port-foward`` to expose port 8080 of the application to your local computer and then access it directly.

Comment: What image are you using for your application though? Others have had issues with Tomcat 8, so the code being used may not be compatible with it. Try Tomcat 7 as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595250/128141

Comment: I got various errors trying to connect to port 8000 and port 80, but removing the port specification completely from the address my client was attempting to connect to got things working for me. Thanks for the help gents. (And to answer your question Graham, I'm using the `rhscl/nodejs-6-rhel7` image.)